# How to replicate a huge table in chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have this huge table 65,000,000 records. We have configured a merge replication, it works ok for the other 300 tables (smaller than 1M records) but for the huge one, it's not working. After some time it hangs forever and it gives different (random) errors.

We know we have a very old sql version (2005) and would like to find a workaround.

I've set a filter for the huge table, so it only replicates rows newer than 2017-01-01, in that case it works perfectly.

However, when I change the filter, so it now replicates rows from 2016-01-01 on (we are trying to do it in chunks) it reinitializes the whole publication, creates a new snapshot and then it hangs again.

Is there some other workaround we may use in order to replicate the data in chunks? We are considering duplicating the huge table, removing rows older than 2017-01-01, start the replication (without filters) then insert rows from 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-31, then the same for rows from year 2015, and so on, until the whole table gets replicated, but it looks a bit scary and tedious.

Comment: Does the table have a PK? If so why not use that to determine new records?

Comment: It has an autoincremental ID, yes. But I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Ok so why can't you store that last PK you processed from that table so the next time all you need to do is to you where clause WHERE OK > LastPK.

Comment: When I change the Filter the whole database is replicated from 0. It reinitializes the publication automatically.

Comment: The initial load for large tables is usually done by a snapshot replication or a restored backup.

Comment: Not sure why you mention that... I have a backup, but the replication starts deleting my whole table on the subscriber and after that it starts replication data

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to simply copy the data manually via a SQL job? Or if there are a lot of changes just use transactional replication. I've done it with tables larger than this.